# We are not getting different page and text as expected in the output XML format using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

XSL is a language for expressing style sheets. An XSL style sheet is, like with CSS, a file that describes how to display an XML document of a given type. Therefore using xml I want convert complete XML into simple XML.

I am getting the XML file from the ABBYY FineReader which is too complex. All I need to convert it into simplified XML.
I have made a XSL file to transform the src.xml to target.xml. But I am not getting the correct expected output file.

If anyone have any idea regarding this please help me as soon as possible.

Here is Complex XML file which I want to convert into simplified XML.

Source Code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" version="1.0" producer="ABBYY FineReader Engine 12" languages="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
        <page width="294" height="189" resolution="120" originalCoords="1">
        <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="0" t="5" r="272" b="185"><region><rect l="0" t="5" r="272" b="185"/></region>
        <text>
        <par lineSpacing="2410">
        <line baseline="30" l="1" t="6" r="72" b="30"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">hello</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1840">
        <line baseline="87" l="0" t="69" r="179" b="87"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">this is a website</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1260">
        <line baseline="136" l="0" t="122" r="269" b="140"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Is the writing getting smaller?</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1260">
        <line baseline="182" l="0" t="169" r="133" b="182"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">IM SHRINKING</formatting></line></par>
        </text>
        <text>
        <par lineSpacing="2410">
        <line baseline="30" l="1" t="6" r="72" b="30"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">10</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1840">
        <line baseline="87" l="0" t="69" r="179" b="87"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">20</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1260">
        <line baseline="136" l="0" t="122" r="269" b="140"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">30</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1260">
        <line baseline="182" l="0" t="169" r="133" b="182"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">40</formatting></line></par>
        </text>
        </block>
        </page>
        
        <page width="294" height="189" resolution="120" originalCoords="1">
        <block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="0" t="5" r="272" b="185"><region><rect l="0" t="5" r="272" b="185"/></region>
        <text>
        <par lineSpacing="2410">
        <line baseline="30" l="1" t="6" r="72" b="30"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">hii</formatting></line></par>
        <par lineSpacing="1840">
        <line baseline="87" l="0" t="69" r="179" b="87"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">Demo for XSL</formatting></line></par>
        </text>
        </block>
        </page>
        </document>
```

***Desired output***

**Here is the simplified XML which I want**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <document>
            <page>
                <block blockType="Text">
                    <text>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>hello</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>this is a website</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>Is the writing getting smaller?</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>IM SHRINKING</line>
                        </paragraph>
                    </text>
                    <text>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>10</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>20</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>30</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>40</line>
                        </paragraph>
                    </text>
                </block>
            </page>
            <page>
                <block blockType="Text">
                    <text>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>hii</line>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph>
                            <line>Demo for XSL</line>
                        </paragraph>
                    </text>
                </block>
            </page>
        </document>
```

***XSL Code***

**Here is the XSL from which we convert Complex XML into simple XML**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <document>
                    <page>
                        <block>
                            <xsl:variable name="blockType" select="/document/page/block/@blockType"/>
                            <!-- The variable blockType can be used for further processing.  -->
                            <xsl:attribute name="blockType"><xsl:value-of select="$blockType"/></xsl:attribute>
                           <xsl:for-each select="/document/page/block/text">
                           <text>
                                <xsl:for-each select="/document/page/block/text/par">
                                    <paragraph>
                                        <line>
                                            <xsl:value-of   select="./line"/>
                                        </line>
                                    </paragraph>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </text>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </block>
                    </page>
                </document>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual output**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <page>
              <block blockType="Text Text">
                 <text>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hello</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>this is a website</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Is the writing getting smaller?</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>IM SHRINKING</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>10</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>20</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>30</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>40</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hii</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Demo for XSL</line>
                    </paragraph>
                 </text>
                 <text>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hello</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>this is a website</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Is the writing getting smaller?</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>IM SHRINKING</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>10</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>20</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>30</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>40</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hii</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Demo for XSL</line>
                    </paragraph>
                 </text>
                 <text>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hello</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>this is a website</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Is the writing getting smaller?</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>IM SHRINKING</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>10</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>20</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>30</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>40</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>hii</line>
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                       <line>Demo for XSL</line>
                    </paragraph>
                 </text>
              </block>
           </page>
        </document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <document>
        <xsl:for-each select="page">
            <page>
                <xsl:for-each select="block">
                    <block blockType="{@blockType}">
                       <xsl:for-each select="text">
                           <text>
                                <xsl:for-each select="par">
                                    <paragraph>
                                        <line>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="line"/>
                                        </line>
                                    </paragraph>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </block>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </page>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or perhaps even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block">
    <block blockType="{@blockType}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>    
    </block>        
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="par">
    <paragraph>
        <line>
            <xsl:value-of select="line"/>
        </line>
    </paragraph>
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't want to add the region and rec tag that's why m not considering the local-name tag.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, see if that works for you.